# ¿Como puedo hacer para que funcione el boton?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

no encuentro la forma para que el boton se "multiplique" acorde con el numero de objetos en la lista. Para que luego, cuando se presione un botón, este muestre en la columna de al lado el objeto que corresponde al nombre del botón.

```
<script>
    Vue.component({
        template:
            `
    <div>
     <h1>Elemento Padre</h1>
     <ul>
     <li>
    <button @click="obtenerDatos">{{ item.name }}</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    `,

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            cursos: []
        },
        mutations: {
            llenarCursos(state, cursosAccion) {
                state.cursos = cursosAccion
            }
        },
        actions: {
            obtenerDatos: async function ({ commit }) {
                const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                const cursos = await data.json();
                commit('llenarCursos', cursos)
            }
        }
    });
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store: store
    })

</script>
```

Comment: De donde viene item.name? ese es el boton que queres que aparezca muchas veces?

Comment: Sí, es ese. Obviamente tengo más código. Pero el editor de preguntas no me permite ponerlo entero

Comment: No se cuanto mas codigo podes tener para un pagina en vue.. pero no creo que sobrepases el maximo. igual, mira por favor [mcve], y pone las partes que importan del codigo. Dado que queres hacer un v-for de una coleccion, deberia estar al menos la coleccion sobre la que lo queres hacer :/

Comment: El store en esta pregunta, no aporta nada.. y no debe tener nada que ver ni con tu problema ni con la solucion ;)